# Unable to accessing Array with JQuery and Display on Table

Tags: html

Trying to Display the : Name | Industry | Current Price to the HTML Table .

Please review my Code and help me display my data on HTML page .

Am i missing something to not able to Display on the HTML ?
Is my way of accessing the array wrong ?

This is my **test.js** script

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

       var test_data = [
                            {
                              "current_price": 1626.0,
                              "name": "HDFC Bank",
                              "industry": "Financials",
                              
                            },
                            {
                              "current_price": 7064.8,
                              "name": "Maruti Suzuki",
                              "industry": "Automobiles",
                            }
                        ];

       $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         test_data += '<tr>' ;
         test_data += '<td>'+val.name+"<td>" ;
         test_data += '<td>'+val.industry+"<td>" ;
         test_data += '<td>'+val.current_price+"<td>" ;
         s_data += '</tr>' ;

       });

       $('#test').appendTo(test_data);

});




Below is my **HTML Page** :
```

```html
<html>
<head> 
Test
 
</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-hover" id="test">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company Name</th>
      <th>Industry </th>
      <th>Current price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of issues with the code. Mostly with names. For example  test_data is the array of data but then test_data is where html is built! Then the jquery loop is iterating through data (and not test_data). Then what is s_data? a typo! Then the closing TDs are missing and then the test_data should be appended to Table and not the other way around.

Here is the working code ([and here is the JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ss0s9LbL/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       var data = [
                            {
                              "current_price": 1626.0,
                              "name": "HDFC Bank",
                              "industry": "Financials",

                            },
                            {
                              "current_price": 7064.8,
                              "name": "Maruti Suzuki",
                              "industry": "Automobiles",
                            }
                        ];

        var test_data = '';
       $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         test_data += '<tr>' ;
         test_data += '<td>'+val.name+"</td>" ;
         test_data += '<td>'+val.industry+"</td>" ;
         test_data += '<td>'+val.current_price+"</td>" ;
         test_data += '</tr>';
       });

       $('#test').append(test_data);

});
```

Comment: I have a Query to ask !
Lets say i have long list array data(10K records) , i can't use the above for such a case .

how can i use a local file and convert to array and then make the same outcome.

Comment: Glad that the solution worked for you. Technically you can very well use the above code for 10K records, it will be just very long file. You can put the var data=[...] code in another JS file and then the other js file will be very long. Usually the 10K records come from DataBase. Best solution will be to use ajax to load data from database. Even better to use paging/chunk of data at a time so you don't hit AJAX data limitation.

Comment: Exactly... i wanted to load the data from another JS file but i'm unable to access the data... 
There is an issue to load data file from local files .

Can you create me a snippet to add the local file of the data array ? and use of it. 
i tried looking but didn't find the answer for it.

Comment: you don't really load data from another JS file. You define the data = [] in another js file and link to it before linking your other js file. so basically you are breaking your long js file into multiple/smaller js files and linking to them. so in html page you will do [script]var data= []; [/script] then [script src='data.js'][/script] and then [script src='functions.js'][/script]. Since data is defined outside the js files as global it can be populated and referenced inside the js files.